# Xcode iOS Simulator Scheme Selector Displaying The Simulator Identifier

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

This is what I see on XCode 6.4. I removed all other versions of XCode and reinstalled 6.4. Let me know how to address this. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All I have to do was to delete copies of the same simulator entry in the Simulator through the Manage Devices and that solved the issue for me.

[image]